# JComboBox não permite troca de item

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um `JComboBox` que permite selecionar apenas o primeiro item clicado, caso eu queira mudar de seleção ele não permite.

No `jPanel` tem outros dois combos que estão idênticos com o que possui o comportamento explicado, mas eles funcionam perfeitamente, caso eu queria mudar de item é permitido.
Já criei um de teste mas o comportamento persiste.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

```java
final JComboBox comboBoxBem = new JComboBox();
comboBoxBem.setToolTipText("Descri\u00E7\u00E3o do Bem");
comboBoxBem.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
comboBoxBem.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
comboBoxBem.setBounds(365, 314, 402, 20);
comboBoxBem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (comboBoxBem.getSelectedItem() != null) {
      try {
        InformacoesDoBemBean informacoesDoBem;
        if (comboBoxBem.getSelectedItem() != null &&
            comboBoxBem.getSelectedItem() instanceof Bem) {
          Bem bem = (Bem)comboBoxBem.getSelectedItem();
          informacoesDoBem = controller.getInformacoesDoBem(bem.getCodigo(),
                                                            bem.getPatrimonio());
          if (informacoesDoBem != null) {
            textFieldNumeroDoBem.setText(informacoesDoBem.getCodigo());
            textFieldResponsavelPelaArea.setText(informacoesDoBem.getNomeResponsavel());
            textFieldPatrimonio.setText(informacoesDoBem.getPatrimonio());
            textPanelDescricao.setText("");
            lblValorCaractRestante.setText("80");
          }
        }
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("####ERRO AO OBTER INFORMAÇÕES DO BEM: ", ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(container,
          "Ocorreu um erro ao carregar as informações do bem, tente novamente");
      }
    }
  }
});
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBoxBem);
container.add(comboBoxBem);
```

Comment: Você implementou devidamente o método `equals()` na classe `Bem`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, não estava implementado de forma correta. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Legal, vou acrescentar como uma resposta para deixarmos a pergunta correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de problema geralmente é causado por uma implementação incorreta do método `equals()` da classe que representa os elementos da JComboBox.

Por exemplo, a seguinte classe reproduz o problema:

```java
public class Bem {

    private String nome;
    public Bem(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == nome; // implementação incorreta, nunca vai retornar verdadeiro
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //combo
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem(new Bem("Teste1"));
        combo.addItem(new Bem("Teste2"));
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (combo.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Selected: " + combo.getSelectedIndex() + " - " + combo.getSelectedItem());
                }
            }
        });

        //window
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Combo");
        f.getContentPane().add(combo);
        f.setSize(200,  200);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Note que o método equals está comparando algo que sempre vai retornar verdadeiro, portanto ao procurar o elemento na lista, o primeiro elemento sempre será o resultado da comparação.

O exemplo abaixo corrige o problema:

```java
public class Bem {

    private String nome;
    public Bem(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Bem)) return false;
        return obj == this || nome.equals(((Bem) obj).nome);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //combo
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem(new Bem("Teste1"));
        combo.addItem(new Bem("Teste2"));
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (combo.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Selected: " + combo.getSelectedIndex() + " - " + combo.getSelectedItem());
                }
            }
        });

        //window
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Combo");
        f.getContentPane().add(combo);
        f.setSize(200,  200);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que você não cometeu nenhum equívoco? Você está comparando `Strings` usando `==`. Além disso, o seu método `equals` dá `ClassCastException` se o tipo do parâmetro não for um `Bem` ou `NullPointerException` se for `null`. Também está faltando o `hashCode()`.

Comment: @Victor Obrigado. Devo ter colado o código errado na resposta. Amanhã irei revisá-la.

Comment: @Victor Realmente havia colado dois exemplos incorretos, devo ter me confundido na hora de editar a resposta. Mais uma vez. Obrigado.